# Passar paramento para Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou a vários dias procurando uma solução mas não encontrei nada que me fosse útil. O problema é o seguinte, tenho um **Conttroller** que recebe os dados da **View**, até aí tudo bem, mas quando eu vou capturar esses dados ele só captura através do método do banco de dados (tabela Usuario) porém queria que ele também guardasse o valor do id em um inteiro.

```
Public actionResult criar ( Usuario usuario, int id)
{
    //Faz o que tem que ser feito 
// Ele só pega o valor no usuario e no id da como nulll


}
```

Comment: você poderia exemplificar melhor o que gostaria, pois, não compreendi.

Comment: Então ,no meu controller eu quero cadastrar os usuários ,até aí de boas ,eu consigo porém quando vou cadastrar novamente o usuário com mesmo id ele dá erro(dá erro porque não pode ter dois id iguais) aí estou usando uma lógica para que ele possa receber o id digitado pelo usuário passando ele para o para controle pelo int id ,ai Assim eu possa trabalhar com o valor e manipular

Comment: Quando eu recebo os dados do usuário meu int id está dizendo que não contém valor , se eu deixar publc actionResult criar (int? Id)da como null e não recebo os dados da viu mas com público actionResult criar ( Usuario usuário) ele recebe os dados

Comment: Tente detalhar melhor sua pergunta. > "...só captura através do método do banco de dados..." isso está meio estranho, receber os dados da View no Controller não deveria ter relação com banco de dados, coloque o código da sua View e seu Model, assim fica mais fácil para o pessoal ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No id seu campo esta vindo como null por que na sua view no form não há nenhum campo como id, Para isso funcionar você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

Faz isto dentro do BegginForm

```
@Html.BegginForm....
```

Que seu valor do id chegará na controller

Comment: Mas dá para pegar o valor do id e do Usuario ao mesmo tempo?no caso Usuario seria o Usuario usuario

Comment: Sim, O ID virá no Usuário e virá na variável do parâmetro

Comment: perfeito,me ajudou muito ,agora consigo trabalhar com os dados ,também estava errando na hora de declara a variável com o mesmo nome.

Comment: Muito bom poder ajudar amigo, Se possivel marque como respondida e de um voto de útil na resposta, Me ajuda muito

Comment: Ainda não tenho pontuação suficiente :(